# Can i add a dropdown menu in dot net nuke 7 main menu from module

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

i am developing a module with the projects info on it. Now i need to add Projects dropdown menu in main menu of DNN 7 with project name as child menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding items into the Navigation of DNN is done by creating pages. You could have your module create pages (Tabs table) that redirect to your module with specific redirects to go to the proper page with the proper querystring parameters.

DNN doesn't have a way for modules to tie into the main navigation of the website.